# how to fix favicon.ico coruppted in springboot (while jpg-s in subfolders are not)?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, favicon

I have a springboot mavenproject that contain image resources in folder

- src/main/resources/static/favicon.ico
- src/main/resources/static/img/cart.jpg

and the corresponding maven script pom.xml contains

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

According to https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html filtering=true replaces placeholders and therefore destroys binary images.

After building the app with `mvn install` my target dir contains these files

- target/classes/static/favicon.ico
- target/classes/static/img/cart.jpg

where favicon.ico is corupted (because of filtering) and img/cart.jpg is not.

**Any idea where protecting img/cart.jpg is done (and can be expanded for favicon.ico) ?**

my current workaround. i have a seperate resource folder "resource-bin" for favicon.ico only

- src/main/resources-bin/static/favicon.ico

with this maven setting

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources-bin</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

I excluded the filtering for .ico by using nonFilteredFileExtensions

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
            <nonFilteredFileExtension>ico</nonFilteredFileExtension>                                                        
        </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>


<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

My favicon.ico is copied without corruption.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by defining two resource configurations. One with filtering enabled and exluding specific directories and/or files and the other one with filtering disabled and including the directory and/or files:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>public/</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>public/</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

This should prevent filtering all resources inside the public directory.
If you are using spring boot you may also need to configure the plugin with addResources false:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
  <configuration>
    <addResources>false</addResources>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

However, this disables the hot refreshing for resources.

Answer (score 0):

You should override default spring boot Favicon by placing the new favicon in the resources directory:

src/main/resources/favicon.ico

At start up spring boot will scan for it at the root resources location

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-favicon